# Would the phrase, "in my area," be a non-restrictive clause?

Tags: clauses

Would "*in my area*" be a non-restrictive clause in the sentence, "*These are the only two parks I know, in my area*"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edited and corrected, thanks to @AlanCarmack:

"In my area" is not a clause, it's a prepositional phrase. "In my area" doesn't have a subject-verb combination and does not form a predicate. Instead, it provides additional context to the clause it is in. "In" is the preposition in this case.

On that note, I think that the comma is incorrect here. The sentence should be,  "These are the only two parks I know in my area." In speech, there may be a pause before, "in my area", but this should not be signified by a comma in writing.

You could also write it as "These are the only two *parks in my area* that I know.

Comment: With the pause, or the comma that represents it, I would take the restriction as an afterthought: "These are the only two parks I know ... _wait, I can't say that, it's nonsense that I only know two parks, I'd better clarify_ .. in my area".

Comment: "in my area"  is a prepositional phrase, not a clause

Comment: @AlanCarmack, but can't it be considered as the elided form of "which are in my area"? And so the restrictive/nonrestrictive distinction applies, like it does to appositives? // Also, what do you you think of Colin Fine's comment? Wouldn't you consider a comma appropriate there then?

Answer (score 2):

*In my area* is a prepositional phrase. It is not a clause. The whole idea of restrictive and non-restrictive clauses refers only to relative clauses as far as I know, and the insertion of commas is largely stylistic in regard to prepositional phrases. I would never use a comma after *know* in

> These are the only two parks I know in my area

because a comma would totally break up the flow of the sentence.

The true relative clause in this sentence is

> [that] I know in my area

and leaving out the relative pronoun *that* and a comma before it makes the clause [restrictive](http://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/restrictive_clause.htm).